# What are some recent significant developments/studies in theoretical nonlinear chemical dynamics?

Tags: reference-request, one-topic-per-answer, atomistic-simulation, nonequilibrium

During my undergraduate studies, I was introduced to oscillatory and nonlinear reactions, which are essentially chemical reactions oscillating far away from equilibrium conditions - A very visual example is the [BZ reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction). As I am not linked to this research area, I was wondering if there are new advancements or significant studies done that enhances our understanding in this field, possibly 2000-present.

[image: BZ reaction]

P.S. It would be great if someone could point to atomistic simulation studies of these reactions, as I couldn't find one as compared to other fields in materials modeling.

Comment: I haven't looked into enough to warrant an answer, but [this article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5120508) describes a recent Focus Issue of the Journal Chaos entitled “Nonlinear Chemical Dynamics and Its Interdisciplinary Impact". They mention a few chemistry related simulation studies.

Comment: Some discussion about this question can be found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61268284#61268284).